# Database stores Wrong date when use datetime.utcnonw() flask-sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to save the current time in my database when I save a review but each time It stores the time as 1990. When I run  `datetime.utcnonw()` on the python shell it returns the correct date. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for my model

```
class Review(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'reviews'

    dates = datetime.now()
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    movie_title = db.Column(db.String)
    image_path = db.Column(db.String)
    movie_review = db.Column(db.String)
    posted = db.Column(db.DateTime(),default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
```

Here is the code inserting it into the database

```
@main.route('/movie/review/new/<int:id>', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def new_review(id):

    form = ReviewForm() #wtf form class that has only two fields
    movie = get_movie(id) # Function that calls an api and returns a movie

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = form.title.data
        review = form.review.data

        new_review = Review(movie_id=movie.id,movie_title=title,image_path=movie.poster,movie_review=review,user=current_user)
    new_review.save_review()

    return redirect(url_for('.movie',id = movie.id ))
```

Comment: What is the current time on the machine hosting the database?

Comment: why are you writing dates = datetime.now() instead of dates = datetime.utcnow()

Comment: Current time is ok like its today's date and time.

Comment: dates = datetime.now() this was testing something else it can be ignored

Comment: show us the code inserting in the db

Comment: @senaps I have added it.

Comment: I tried to replicate this on Postgresql 9.5 and was not able to reproduce the problem.   Would it be possible to test with a newer version of postgresql just to ensure this is not a feature of an old version?